# Load my custom JS for every page I visit

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm not sure how to phrase this...

I'm trying to use jquery inside a browser (at the browser console) to do website automation.

Here's a couple examples of what I'm doing...I just paste this into the browser js console:

```
var scr = document.createElement("script");
scr.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(scr);

highlight = function(name) {
    $("a:contains('"+name+"')").css("background","red");
}

click = function(name) {
    $("a:contains('"+name+"')")[0].click();
}
```

`highlight()` and `click()` work perfectly, but when the browser's url changes (i.e. I called `click()`), the above js that was executed in the last page's console is gone...so I have to paste the above js into the console again.

It's not a big deal to paste it in each time, but since that's not programmable, it breaks my use case.

**Summary:** How do I either load up some javascript in my browser that will persist (the env will persist) between pages, or ask my browser (any browser is fine) to load my script again with each pageload? I'd be happy to even use a browser extension if you know of one that works.

Comment: What you are describing *is* a browser extension; you will need to develop one.

Comment: P.S. If what you are really wanting is browser automation, you might also check out [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: You can create a simple bookmarklet, too. Then simply drag it from your bookmarks bar to the page everytime (bit less tedious than console). Note that some sites don't allow script tag injection though (eg. social media)

Comment: 1.) If u don't want to lose your `console log upon navigation`, right click in `console` and tick `Preserve Log upon Navigation`. Now u won't lose your log from earlier pages.     2.) You don't need to `copy-paste` your js code every time. Just press `UP-Arrow-key` and your script would appear in your console. Press `Enter` to execute the script.      3.) Simply make a chrome-extension, which injects your js code to every page.

Answer (score 2):

@EdCottrell is correct that an actual browser automation tool like Selenium might be more appropriate for your purpose.

If you're looking, however, for a way to run a script on every page during everyday use, the term commonly used is "userscript," and there are addons available for most browsers to enable you to write and use them.

The granddaddy of userscript tools is the Firefox addon [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/). Chrome actually has userscript support built-in, but [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) is an extension that makes it easier to manage them. There are addons for other browsers, too, but I haven't used them. The [Wikipedia article on Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) gives a good overview. Good luck!